# Object to JSON issue in RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

The Rest API I am using has a new field called Api-Key.  This is not a valid C# field name so I am wondering if there is a different way of building the body.

```
   var client = new RestClient("https://TestWeb");

        var request = new RestRequest("login", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        request.AddJsonBody(
           new {
               credentials =
            new
            {
                username = "Uname",
                password = "password",
                Api-Key = "apikey"
            } });
```

Comment: RestSharp has been a fantastic library to use in this application so I am really hoping there is a way around this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `RestSharp` uses as default Json serializer `SimpleJson` that, for what I know, doesn't support attributes to change serialization behaviour, I would:

1. Install as NuGet package [Newtonsoft Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), in order to use its `JsonProperty` attribute.
2. Define a class to provide an authentication object like this:

   ```
   public class AuthenticationInfos
   {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "username")]
       public string Username { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "password")]
       public string Password { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Api-Key")]
       public string ApiKey { get; set; }
   }
   ```

(The key part is here `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Api-Key")]`, you are telling the serializer to serialize that property with that name, which is invalid as a C# variable)

3. Use Newtonsoft Json serialization to serialize the body request:

   ```
   var client = new RestClient("https://TestWeb");

   var request = new RestRequest("login", Method.POST);
   request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

   var body = new
   {
       credentials =
           new AuthenticationInfos()
           {
               Username = "Uname",
               Password = "password",
               ApiKey = "myApiKey"
           }
   };

   var serializedBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
   request.AddParameter("application/json", serializedBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
   ```

The body will be like:

```
{
    "credentials":
    {
        "username": "Uname", 
        "password": "password",
        "Api-Key": "myApiKey"
    }
}
```

Of course you'll have to the same in deserialization phase when receiving the message.

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thanks.